# HTML J2ME Problem

Tags: html, blackberry, java-me, xml-parsing, arabic

i'm trying to put large amount of data in a java me application for a BlackBerry mobile and i noticed that the max file size to be accepted in BlackBerry is 150 KB, by the way i'm developping the application in arabic language so i'm converting every litter to his corresponding unicode so every char gets to 6 chars so its another big problem, some ppl told me that i can write arabic as arabic letters without the need to write its unicode, by viewing the mobile form as an html page,

my problem is that i dont know how to view the page as html page and what is XMLParser ??
can anyone help me to get all this together, cos i really need some serious help

thank you alot
Hesham

Comment: There are arabic encodings that  are smaller than Unicode, but it's not advisable to switch to them - UTF-8 really is the future of web development. I would start with the root problem first: Why do you have such large HTML documents in the first place? Is that really all needed data?

Comment: Are you trying to open HTML page or parse it and visualize it according to needs of your application?

Comment: yes i'm afraid that i cant discard any of these data, thats what i need to fine a way to minimize the size of files and writing in unicode takes alot of space thats why i wanna write arabic in arabic not in unicode and i think there r no other way but to write it on html page

Comment: i wanna parse it and visualize it to my app.

Comment: @Hesham and that visualization has to take place inside the client device?

Comment: yes, beside i cant upload this data to a server cos not all my clients use internet services

Comment: When you say there is a 150kb limit, I'm not sure what that is in reference to.  What version of BBOS are you targeting?

Comment: beside Michael Donohue comment, I don't see why you are using the escaped unicode, you just need to save your file in UTF-8 and read them using the correct encoding.

Comment: Mr. Mahdi i'm pretty confused about saving my file as UTF-8 and reading it, would u plz explain how can i save it and how can i read it correctly ??, maybe thats my problem

Comment: @Mr. Michael i dont really see any difference with the BBOS cos the problem of data get generated while i'm compiling my project on the netbeans platform, its just say thet the data section is too large, so by trying i found that this error disappear when my data file is less than 150 KB

Comment: i really need some serious help cos i'm stuck in this point and i dont know what to do :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> arabic language so i'm converting
>   every litter to his corresponding
>   unicode so every char gets to 6 chars

I assume you mean the Java unicode escape form when you say 6 chars, such as "\u0600"
When the Java compiler sees this, it turns it into the single character representation that matches this Unicode code point.   So there is no overhead to using this way of specifying unicode characters.